# os.rename path error while moving file to subdirectory

Tags: python, file-copying, shutil

I am new to python and coding in general. I have spent a lot of time trying to fix this error but I am not able to figure out how to do this. I have a main folder that contains a subfolder, I want to move files from the main folder to subfolder. This should be done easily by `os.rename` or `shutil.move` but I am not able to fix this error. Below is the code that I am using and the error that I am getting.

```
cdir=os.getcwd()
newdir=cdir+"\subfolder"
src=os.path.join(cdir, fname) 
dst=os.path.join(newdir, fname)
os.rename(src,dst)
```

The error shows a double backslash in the directories path i.e.

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'E:\\
>   folder\\fname' -> 'E:\\folder\\subfolder\\fname'

the correct path would be with single back slashes. I am using windows 8.1 and python34. Can any one help me with this. I know this question must be a duplicate but I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Similar error is generated with `shutil.move`

Comment: Could be wrong, but I'd have thought that newdir=cdir+"\subfolder" needs a double slash to escape it

Comment: @RodHyde: `\s` is not a valid escape sequence, so that's not an issue. Still, using `os.path.join(cdir, 'subfolder')` would be better, with `os.path.abspath('subfolder')` being best (as it'll base that of the current working dir).

Comment: The double backslashes just mean the backslashes are escaped; Python is showing you the error message as a string you can copy to reproduce the exact value. You have a **different** problem.

Comment: Did you create that folder before trying to more files to it?

Comment: I have tried printing the src and dst, that gives me the correct desired path. i.e.E:\folder\fname and E:\folder\subfolder\fname

only when I use shutil.move or os.rename that I get these double back slashes in the path names and get an error.

Comment: @SyedMoez: again, the double backslashes are **normal** and are not the issue. The `subfolder` does need to be created *first*.

Comment: @tobias_k I have tried it doing by creating a folder and without the subfolder. same error

Comment: Just to make sure, do `os.mkdir(newdir)` before `os.rename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double backslashes are *normal*; they are not the cause of the error. Python always doubles up backslashes in string representations so that you can safely copy that value into a Python interpreter and reproduce the exact string:

```
>>> print 'E:\\folder\\fname' 
E:\folder\fname
>>> 'E:\\folder\\fname' 
'E:\\folder\\fname'
>>> value = 'E:\\folder\\fname' 
>>> value
'E:\\folder\\fname'
>>> print value
E:\folder\fname
```

Python does this because a single backslash is used in escape sequences; `'\n'` is a newline, but `'\\n'` is a backslash and the letter `n`.

Your error lies elsewhere; most likely the `subfolder` has yet to be created; `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()` will not create parent folders for you.

You can use the [`os.makedirs()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to ensure that all folders in a path are created:

```
newdir = os.path.abspath('subfolder')  # will use the current working directory
try:
    # ensure that it exists
    os.makedirs(newdir)
except OSError:
    pass  # it is already there
src = os.path.abspath(fname) 
dst = os.path.join(newdir, fname)
os.rename(src, dst)
```

You also need to make sure you don't accidentally use single backslashes in your filename or subfolder definitions; `\s` is not a valid escape, but others *are* valid and can produce unexpected results. Double the backslash in strings defining paths, or use a *raw string literal*, or use forward slashes instead:

```
>>> '\new'  # newline!
'\new'
>>> print '\new'  # produces a blank line in between

ew
>>> '\\new'
'\\new'
>>> print '\\new'
\new
>>> r'\new'
'\\new'
>>> '/new'
'/new'
```

Windows accepts forward slashes just fine; it doesn't care if the path separator is pointing forward or backward.

Comment: Is the syntax that I am using for os.rename correct? I will try again creating a different folder

Comment: @SyedMoez: are you certain `fname` exists as well? In all cases, be careful using ``\`` in a filename definition in Python. Double backslashes, use a raw string literal (`r'...'`) or use *forward* slashes (Windows accepts those too) as the path separator.

Comment: @martijin Pieters: You are right, using backslash to define the new folder and to defines the subdirectory and it was being considered as an escape sequence. Thanks a lot, you explained in great detail. This helps a lot.